# jQuery update current price based on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to update current field value when customer checks additional options.

I have few checkboxes, input fields with different values.

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="item-price-checkbox" name="equipment_1" value="20">
 <input type="checkbox" class="item-price-checkbox" name="equipment_2" value="30">
 <input type="checkbox" class="item-price-checkbox" name="equipment-3" value="50">
```

Current price for car is 100$. When customer checks equipment_1, it adds its price to the existing price. So in this case it will be `100$ + 20$ = 120$`.  My script does not work properly. Because when i check something i do not get `120` i get `10020`. So addition does not work properly.

```
var basePrice = $(".price_field").val();

$(".item-price-checkbox").change(function() {
    var newPrice = basePrice;

    $('.item-price-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        newPrice += $(this).val();
        // newPrice = newPrice + $(this).val();
    });

    $('.price_field').val(newPrice);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the received value into `number`,

```
var basePrice = parseInt($(".price_field").val(),10);

$(".item-price-checkbox").change(function() {
    var newPrice = basePrice;
    $('.item-price-checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        newPrice += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    });
    $('.price_field').val(newPrice);
});
```

Basically, `.val()` will return the typed values in the form of string. we have to convert it manually to number. Also don't forget to pass the `radix` parameter while parsing a `string` to `number`. If you don't then the conversion will be happened differently as per the supplied string.

Comment: Deam ur right, `val` return string i cant calculate `string + number`. Thanks now perfect work. I will accept aswer (5 min)